# Why does var$ compile but var@ doesn't?

Tags: c, gcc, operators, clang, variable-names

Take this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int var$ = 3;
    printf("%d\n",var$);
}
```

This compiles properly ([GCC](http://rextester.com/EGJFS92100), [Clang](http://rextester.com/BKWDR96741), [MSVC](http://rextester.com/TXP8386)) and prints `3` upon execution as expected.

However, this code:

```
int main(void)
{
    int var@ = 8;
    printf("%d\n",var@);
}
```

This does not compile ([GCC](http://rextester.com/IFCRUY13166), [Clang](http://rextester.com/JWZ92565), [MSVC](http://rextester.com/YGIHW76330)), with the error `stray '@' in program`.

Looking at the [C/C++ Operator List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) (<kbd>Ctrl+F</kbd>'ing for `@` and `$`), neither of them are operators.

Why is `var$` valid but `var@` isn't?

Comment: It may be an unsubstantiated rumour, but I believe that VMS (which used to be used as an o/s on DEC VAX machines) had system calls etc that embedded `$` in the names, so compilers that ran on VMS needed to allow `$` as a valid symbol in identifiers.  This may have been carried over more generally.  It allows you to write non-portable and obscure code.  _…time passes…or it may be a [substantiated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43955862/) [rumour](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43955894/)!…_

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Surely [there's proof out there somewhere](http://h41361.www4.hpe.com/docs/base_doc/DOCUMENTATION/V40F_PDF/AQTLTBTE.PDF#page=27).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at the [C11 Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), Section 6.4.2 on Identifiers:

> #### Semantics
>
> **2** An identifier is a sequence of nondigit characters (including the underscore `_`, the
>   lowercase and uppercase Latin letters, and other characters) and digits, which designates
>   one or more entities as described in 6.2.1. Lowercase and uppercase letters are distinct.
>   There is no specific limit on the maximum length of an identifier.
>
> **3** Each universal character name in an identifier shall designate a character whose encoding
>   in ISO/IEC 10646 falls into one of the ranges specified in D.1.<sup>71)</sup> The initial character
>   shall not be a universal character name designating a character whose encoding falls into
>   one of the ranges specified in D.2. **An implementation may allow multibyte characters
>   that are not part of the basic source character set to appear in identifiers;** which characters
>   and their correspondence to universal character names is implementation-defined.

(emphasis mine)

And per the [GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Implementation-defined-behavior.html#Implementation-defined-behavior) on Implementation-defined behavior:

> - Identifier characters.
>
> The C and C++ standards allow identifiers to be composed of ‘`_`’ and the alphanumeric characters. C++ also allows universal character names. C99 and later C standards permit both universal character names and implementation-defined characters.
>
> **GCC allows the ‘`$`’ character in identifiers as an extension for most targets**. This is true regardless of the `std=` switch, since this extension cannot conflict with standards-conforming programs. When preprocessing assembler, however, dollars are not identifier characters by default.

(emphasis mine)

And again in [Tokenization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization), and mentioned in [Idav1s's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43955862/5647260):

> As an extension, GCC treats ‘`$`’ as a letter. This is for compatibility with some systems, such as VMS, where ‘`$`’ is commonly used in system-defined function and object names. ‘`$`’ is not a letter in strictly conforming mode, or if you specify the `-$` option.

Because VMS used many system-defined functions and objects that were named *with `$`*, GCC allowed `$` to be included as an implementation-specific character for compatibility on some systems.

Special characters such as `$` and `@` aren't explicitly allowed by C specification to be in an identifier, but certain characters (such as `$` here) may be allowed by implementation. GCC, for example allows `$` in identifiers for most targets. The same goes for Clang (as most of its implementation-defined behavior is the same as GCC), and MSVC.

Comment: Re: "Special characters such as `$` and `@` aren't allowed by specification to be in an identifier". This is a bit confusing in relation to the `VMS` part you mentioned before, as I know that `DEC C` allows `$` to be in identifiers, although `@` is not.

Comment: @I'L'l Yeah, I agree. My intention was to say that in the specification, only alphanumeric and _ characters are allowed in identifiers, but certain implementations may define certain other characters to allow. I'll edit to make it clearer

Comment: Forgive me for not understanding, but *why* does GCC accept `@` but not `$`?

Comment: @0xBADC0DE GCC doesn't accept `@` but accepts `$` because the GCC implementation allows for that certain character. Since GCC wanted compatibility, they allowed for `$` in identifiers, but not `@`.

Answer (score 2):

[Blame VMS](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Tokenization.html#Tokenization):

> As an extension, GCC treats ‘$’ as a letter. This is for compatibility with some systems, such as VMS, where ‘$’ is commonly used in system-defined function and object names. ‘$’ is not a letter in strictly conforming mode, or if you specify the -$ option. See Invocation.

I modified your `var$` snippet slightly (to eliminate warnings we don't care about) and added strictly conforming flags [here](http://rextester.com/ZCFR27178):

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=gnu99  -ansi -pedantic -Werror  -O2 -o a.out source_file.c

Error(s):
source_file.c: In function ‘main’:
source_file.c:4:13: error: '$' in identifier or number [-Werror]
         int var$ = 3;
             ^
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

So if `gcc` is given the right flags, `$` won't compile either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, strictly speaking, `var$` isn't valid, either.

Some compilers let you use `$` as a character in identifiers, along with `a`-`z`, `A`-`Z`, `0`-`9`, and `_`.  This is a nonstandard extension.  It's useful because compilers for some other languages (I think including FORTRAN) permit `$` in identifiers, and you might be trying to write C code that interoperates with those other languages.  Evidently gcc is one of the compilers that permits this extension.

An extension permitting `@` would be much more unusual.  I might have seen a weird compiler once that let you use it, but since there's no use for it that I know of, and less demand for it, I guess nobody's offering it.

Comment: I'm not asking about `%`. I'm asking  about `@`.

Comment: Whoops, sorry, fixed.